# How to combine these two graphs in one graph?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

[first graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ocvy.png)

[second graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKmBR.png)

I tried this script :

```
X = np.arange( 0, 100)
Quantum_cost_np_q_time = result_df_Quantum_cost['Quantum Cost Execution Time (in s)'].to_numpy()
classical_cost_np_q_time = result_df_classical_cost['Classical Cost Execution Time (in s)'].to_numpy()

plt.plot(X, Quantum_cost_np_q_time, color = 'red', label = 'Quantum_cost_time' )
plt.plot(X, classical_cost_np_q_time, color = "green", label = 'classical_cost_time' )
plt.xlabel("index")
plt.ylabel("execution time")
plt.title("cost")
  
# Adding legend, which helps us recognize the curve according to it's color
plt.legend()
  
# To load the display window
plt.show()
```

I want one graph to compare the two graphs :)

Comment: I'm removing the Matlab tag, because this question is not about Matlab

Comment: Welcome to SO! You tried the script and what happened?

Comment: here is what happen :

ValueError                           
Input In [97], in <cell line: 5>()
      2 Quantum_cost_np_q_time = result_df_Quantum_cost['Quantum Cost Execution Time (in s)'].to_numpy()
      3 classical_cost_np_q_time = result_df_classical_cost['Classical Cost Execution Time (in s)'].to_numpy()
----> 5 plt.plot(X, Quantum_cost_np_q_time, color = 'red', label = 'Quantum_cost_time' )
      6 plt.plot(X, classical_cost_np_q_time, color = "green", label = 'classical_cost_time' )
      7 plt.xlabel("index")

Comment: thanks for replying :)

this what happens, I put the screenshot in this drive :)
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cKidW-ZyQ2ZCL7obkb5gG14tBNawqnTp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: when you print the `y` variable, do you get an array? Is this array the same length as the `x` variable?

Comment: Please add reproducible test data. Please add a concrete programming-related question. Please  add full error traces as text, never as an image.